# Removing IDs based on months

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have a data set ranging from the first of January 2010 to the end of Decemeber 2012. I would like to identify `ID`s with specific months present, then filter all of those `ID`s from the data set without filtering out the specific months for those `ID`s.

For example:
If `ID` "B" was missing `Month` 2 (not simulated in the data set below), I would like to remove `ID` "B" from the whole data set, and keep on A, C, and D with all of the months in the data set for those `ID`s intact.

How would I do this?

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
date <- rep_len(seq(dmy("01-01-2010"), dmy("31-12-2011"), by = "days"), 5000)
ID <-  rep(c("A","B","C"), 5000)
df <- data.frame(date = date,
                 x = runif(length(date), min = 60000, max = 80000),
                 y = runif(length(date), min = 800000, max = 900000),
                 ID)

df$jDate <- yday(as.Date(df$date))
df$Month <- month(df$date)
df$year <- year(df$date)

set.seed(1234)
drop_rows <- sapply(sample(1:nrow(df), 3), function(i) {
  return(i:(i+100))
}, simplify = FALSE) %>% unlist()

df <- df[-c(drop_rows), ]
```

Comment: I think you're saying that for each `year`, if an `ID` is missing a month (or more), then remove all of that year for the `ID`? Or is it agnostic to year, and therefore if any month is missing (regardless of year) that ID should be removed? It would really help to have a representative dataset, specifically with at least one triggering "missingness" (and perhaps a lot smaller, I think we don't need 20K rows to demonstrate this).

Comment: It would be the former; for each year, if an `ID` is missing a month (or more), then remove all of that year for the `ID`.

Comment: Two BTWs: (1) your data does not range as you think, `range(df$date)` yields `[1] "2010-01-01" "2011-05-15"`. (2) No need for your latest `as.Date`, just `df$jDate <- yday(df$date)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may group by 'year', and 'ID', get the number of distinct (`n_distinct`) 'Month', check if it is equal to 12 in `filter`.  If an 'year', 'ID' doesn't have 12 unique months, that will be dropped

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(year, ID) %>% 
   filter(n_distinct(Month) == 12) %>% 
   ungroup
```

Comment: Is this removing all `ID`s that don't have all 12 months? Just want to understand it a little more.

Comment: @JohnHuang i updated with some description.  Hope it helps